# Segmentation fault caused after iterating through a queue. Possibly caused by unique_ptr?

Tags: c++

I keep getting a seg fault when I run an autocomplete function.

gdb gives the following seg fault error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
std::__uniq_ptr_impl<cs19::CompactStringSet::Node, std::default_delete<cs19::CompactStringSet::Node> >::_M_ptr (this=0x8) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_ptr.h:173
173           pointer    _M_ptr() const { return std::get<0>(_M_t); }
```

This is kind of a lot to post, the main part of the code to look at is right after the comment that says `// step 3` to the end. I'm including the rest mostly for context.

In my function `std::get<0>` is a pointer. The seg fault might be because of the `pop()`, though in gdb it performed a `pop()` on one element prior to getting the seg fault. I'm using `unique_ptrs` which I'm not super familiar with, I know they're supposed to auto delete but I may be making errors in the implementation. The error is at `while(sibling->sibling)`.

The function is expected to go through a dataset of chars which are linked in `child/sibling` fashion and return a `std::vector` of the fastest matches, but no more than `n`.

I know seg faults aren't cut-and-dry so I don't expect an exact answer, anything helps!

```
std::vector<std::string> CompactStringSet::autocomplete(const std::string& base, std::size_t n) const {    
    // check children, if no match -> check siblings, if no match -> return empty vector; after
    // all matches to base, check all base->child->sibling then check each ->child
    // each option, add any which evaluate to terminal. Exit after n have been found,
    // or no options remain
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    std::queue<std::pair<const Node*, std::string>> matches;
    const Node* cur = &this->root_;
    std::size_t numResults = 0;
    // step 1 : READ IN BASE, MAKE SURE IT'S VALID
    for (auto let : base) {
        if (cur->child) {
            if (cur->child->letter == let) {
                cur = cur->child.get();
                continue;
            }
        }
        Node* sibling = cur->child.get();
        while (sibling->sibling) {
            sibling = sibling->sibling.get();
            if (sibling->letter == let) {
                cur = sibling;
                continue;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
    // step 2 : start from after base and check options  make sure if terminal
    //          and initialize queue
    if (cur->child) {
        std::string toAdd = base + cur->child->letter;
        auto newElem = std::make_pair(cur->child.get(), toAdd);
        matches.push(newElem);
    }
    Node* newSibling = cur->child.get();
    while (newSibling->sibling) {
        newSibling = newSibling->sibling.get();
        std::string toAdd = base + newSibling->letter;
        auto newElem = std::make_pair(newSibling, toAdd);
        matches.push(newElem);
    }
    // step 3 : check each node*, if terminal add to results
    do {
        // check first in queue
        auto elem = matches.front();
        auto curNode = std::get<0>(elem);
        auto curStr = std::get<1>(elem);
        if (std::get<0>(elem)->terminal) {
            results.push_back(std::get<1>(elem));
            ++numResults;
        }
        if (curNode->child) {
            std::string updated = curStr + curNode->child->letter;
            auto newElem = std::make_pair(curNode->child.get(), updated);
            matches.push(newElem);
        }
        Node* sibling = curNode->child.get();
        while (sibling->sibling) {                // where error message occured
            sibling = sibling->sibling.get();
            std::string updated = curStr + sibling->letter;
            auto newElem = std::make_pair(sibling, updated);
            matches.push(newElem);
        }
        matches.pop();
    } while (numResults < n && matches.size() > 0);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to figure out your problem.

Comment: This code looks like a good candidate to run under `valgrind` to see what earlier memory-handling problems valgrind can detect before the segfault occurs.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thanks, I'll try to run it under valgrind

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error is here:

```
    if (cur->child) {
        if (cur->child->letter == let) {
            cur = cur->child.get();
            continue;
        }
    }

    Node* sibling = cur->child.get();
    while (sibling->sibling) {
```

In particular, the `if (cur->child)` test in the first line quoted above indicates that the code's author knows that `cur->child` might be a null `unique_ptr`, and is guarding against that possibility.  Fair enough.  But then just below that we have this code that sets `sibling` equal to (whatever `cur->child` points to, taken as a raw-pointer) and tries to dereference `sibling` in the next line.  In this case, if `cur->child` was `NULL`, then `sibling` will also be NULL, and therefore trying to evaluate `sibling->sibling` will cause a segfault.